# LEFT JOIN in MySQL across multiple tables with NULL values

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join

I have the following table structure with data

`TABLE: USER
 USER ID | USER NAME
 1      | Joe
 2      | Mary`

`TABLE : USER GROUP
USER ID | GROUP ID
 1      |  1
 1      |  2`

`TABLE : GROUP 
GROUP ID | GROUP NAME
 1       | Company 1
 2       | Company 2`

`TABLE : ROLE
 ROLE ID | ROLE NAME
   1     | Administrator
   2     | Users`

`TABLE : USER ROLE
 USER ID | ROLE ID
 1       |  1
 2       |  1`

As you can see user #2 does not belong to any group. Roles & Groups are optional forcing me to left joint but when I run a query as below

```
`SELECT a.user_id,
        a.user_name
        GROUP_CONCAT(r.role_name) AS role_names,
        GROUP_CONCAT(g.group_name) AS group_names
 FROM  user a
  LEFT JOIN role_map m ON a.user_id = m.user_id
     INNER JOIN role r ON m.role_id = r.role_id
  LEFT JOIN user_group s ON a.user_id = s.user_id
     INNER JOIN group g ON s.group_id = g.group_id
 GROUP BY a.user_id`
```

I get a cartesian product in the `role_names` column - the result looks like this

`Joe | Administrators, Administrators | Company 1, Company 2`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what happens when you make all four joins `LEFT JOINS`?

Comment: just tried - same result

Comment: add `GROUP BY a.user_id`??? And also add `DISTINCT` inside your `GROUP_CONCAT`'s

Comment: sorry - yes, i already have a group by clause. updated the original post to reflect that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve this is by using `DISTINCT` in your `GROUP_CONCAT` ([**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4d7f0/10/0)).  Also, you will need to add `GROUP BY a.user_id` in order to group per user:

```
SELECT a.user_id,
       a.user_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT r.role_name) AS role_names,
       GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT g.group_name) AS group_names
FROM  `user` a
  LEFT JOIN `user_role` m ON a.user_id = m.user_id
  LEFT JOIN `role` r ON m.role_id = r.role_id
  LEFT JOIN `user_group` s ON a.user_id = s.user_id
  LEFT JOIN `group` g ON s.group_id = g.group_id
GROUP BY a.user_id;
```

Comment: This would be great - but see the other problem is that `Mary` isnt being returned at all - any idea what is the problem there?

Comment: **@ChicagoSky**, oops forgot to add `GROUP BY a.user_id`.  I updated my answer.  It should work for you now.

Comment: Thanks I have accepted your answer - could you explain what is happening under the scenes so I can figure out why your LEFT joins work but my INNER joins dont

Comment: You have an inner join on the `role` and `group` tables.  Since there is no records returned for `user_name` of **Mary** for either of those tables, Mary will not be included in the results.